# Phonegap Installation , Its App creation and Deployment onto cross mobile platform

Tags: cordova

Hello I am new in phonegap technology , I don't know anything about phonegap . I search on Google , its open source(phonegap.com) but I was getting confused.There are multiple resources which tells different ways about phonegap installation and its app creation.

I want to create application in phonegap and want to deploy it on multiple paltform. Is there any proper solution or easiest way about its installation , then how to create app in phonegap using which tools(tools required,resources required too) and how we can deploy it on various mobile platform.

Comment: which platforms android or ios?

Comment: Android But I want to use it on ios too. I don't know about ios , but using phonegap I want to use app on different mobile platform like ios,blackberry,windows.

Answer (score 0):

Now create phonegap projects is very easy using AppLaud

[Ref this](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start)

and

[Ref this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html)